# Select date in UIDatePicker from UITextField click event MonoTouch

Tags: objective-c, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

First, I have an TextField. When user click on it, DatePicker will appear (in the same textfield's view). After user choose date, DatePicker should be disappear, and textfield should show selected date.

I have tried this code in ViewDidLoad:

```
    txtTime.TouchDown += (sender, e) => {
    UIDatePicker picker = new UIDatePicker (new RectangleF (0, 20, this.View.Bounds.Width, 10));  
    picker.Date = DateTime.Now;
    picker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Time;
    this.Add(picker);
    txtTime.ResignFirstResponder();             
};
```

But I have some problem:

1. Can't disable keyboard (ResignFirstResponder() doesn't work)
2. I don't know how to handle select date even of DatePicker to set for Textbox
3. The DatePicker appear without 'close' or 'done' button, so can't return to textfield view (could I use Datepicker without actionsheet?).

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book ["Developing CSharp Apps for iPhone and iPad using MonoTouch - 2011"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430231742), chapter 7 "Standard Controls" you could see example of how to implement picking date.

Basic idea is to:

- Put DatePicker on a UIActionSheet (create custom class, which controls DatePicker and UIActionSheet actually);
- Add label "Choose date, then press OK" and buttons "OK"/"Cancel" to the top side of UIActionSheet's View;
- Show UIActionSheet on textField.EditingDidBegin event.

Screenshot:

[image: How it looks like]

Sorry for Russian locale settigs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried this way about 2 days ago, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.txtTime.shouldreturn += (txtTime) => {
txtTime.resignfirstresponder ();
return true;
}
```